# Node Permission

Tags: nodes

I have a custom content type, called List (for example).

All members can create new list node from their account, but the admin can also do the same.

What i am looking to get done is, make it so that the node created by admin is shown on top of their list and also could not be deleted except by the admin itself.

Could some one please help me determine the right process to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'shown on top of their list' - but you can adjust the permissions so that only the Admin can edit or delete ALL content of that content type. /Admin/People/Permissions under Node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it can be achieved in 2 steps:

1. Fix permissions. go to admin/people/permissions and for that user group allow only to delete their own content. Don't check List: Delete any content. Then users will be able to delete only their own content.
2. You need to create rule "After saving new content" add condition "User has role" select your role (you need to create one and add for admin). Add action "Node: make content sticky"

Comment: Thanks, this seems like what i need.. I will try it out soon and mark this as the answer.